# Creating a lowercase constant of a particular type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, constants, lowercase

For example, how to define a lowercase constant "corn" of an already existing datatype [Vegetables]?

I have tried using

```
type corn = [Vegetables]
```

but it produced a "Malformed head of type and or class declaration"...

I would like to receive some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Types have to start with a capital letter. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines#Naming_Conventions.

Comment: If not with "type", then how to create a lowercase constant as requested above?

Comment: It's impossible.  Lowercase means *variable*.

Comment: @Warditive a) Why does it have to be lower case? b) What you tried to define is not a constant but a type synonym. c) Do you perhaps want to define a _value_?

Comment: a) My assignment requires that. b) I understand now, thank you for explaining me :). c) Do you mean a value of a particular datatype? If so, please give me an example.

Comment: There's the `id :: (corn ~ [Vegetables]) => corn -> corn` "solution", but I don't think this is what Warditive is after, somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a reasonable guess at what you mean, and the constructors of the `Vegetables` type...

```
corn :: [Vegetables]
corn = [Corn]
```

This is the same as any other top-level level binding. The type signature isn't even necessary, just often-handy documentation.